# ApolloClient: optimisticResponse becomes "undefined" during update

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm trying to do an `optimisticResponse` in a mutation with ApolloClient with vue-apollo.

The mutation itself works fine - the server gets updated, and when I refresh the page, the insert has successfully appeared. However, the `optimisticResponse` that gets written to the query becomes "undefined" once the `update()` function runs for the second time, with the "real" response from the server.

My mutation code looks like this:

```
this.$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: UPSERT_ITEMS,
  variables: {
    todoInput: [todoInput]
  },

  update: (store, result) => {
    const upsertTodos = result.data!.upsertTodos
    const newTodo = upsertTodos.todo
    const data = store.readQuery<QueryResult>({ query: GET_PROJECTS })
    console.log("Results from the cache:", data);
    data!.rc_todos.push(newTodo)
    console.log("after that push, data looks like...", data)
    store.writeQuery({ query: GET_PROJECTS, data })

    // re-reading the query for debugging purposes:
    const sameData = store.readQuery<QueryResult>({ query: GET_PROJECTS })
    console.log("New results from the cache:", sameData)
  },
  optimisticResponse: {
    __typename: "Mutation",
    upsertTodos: {
      __typename: "InsertedTodo",
      id: 1,
      todo_id: 1,
      todo: {
        id: 1,
        label: nodeTitle,
        children: [],
        __typename: "rc_todos"
      }
    },
  },
})
```

Note that right now I'm calling `readQuery` a second time in `update()` for debugging purposes.

In that second call of `readQuery` in the first run of `update()` (i.e. right after inserting `optimisticResponse` it looks like this:
[image]
...so everything looks fine, the fields there match the data that was already in the cache, etc.

But, when `update()` runs the second time (to process results from the server) our `optimisticResponse` is "there" but as `undefined`:
[image]

This yields an error `TypeError: Cannot read property '__typename' of undefined`.

To be honest, I'm not sure what's supposed to be happening at this point in the lifecycle... should optimisticResult still be there? Or should it have already been removed? In either case, I'm sure it shouldn't be there and `undefined` since that's causing the error.

Comment: I suspect it could have something to do with mutating the cache directly. I would try `store.writeQuery({ query: GET_PROJECTS, data: { rc_todos: [...data.rc_todos, newTodo] } })`. That will create a new array instead of mutating the one you got from the cache.

Comment: I just tried it out, unfortunately no luck.

Comment: May just be a bug with apollo-client then although I haven't seen that issue with optimistic update before. You might want to try updating to the latest version (3.0 is available now) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a silly mistake- the real response from the mutation the server was returning was a different shape than how it was set up in the client.

The part I screenshotted in my question is actually the intended behavior- it sets the previously added `optimisticResponse` to `undefined` so as to remove it once the "real" data is available.